# Rails Pagination - first page items amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, infinite-scroll, kaminari

Is there a way to put more items on the first page than the rest of the pages, when using pagination in Rails?

I am using the Kaminari gem to paginate a list of items and have implemented infinite scroll to browse through the pages.  I want to limit the number of listings loaded per page when scrolling, but would like the initial page to start with a significant amount.  Below is the current call to Kaminari in my listings controller:

```
@listings = Listing.page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

Comment: The easiest way to do that might just be to write some JS to trigger loading the second page of results right away -- that way you don't need to do wacky math or logic on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
@listings = Listing.page(params[:page]).per(params[:page].to_i == 1 ? 100 : 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this (First page items is supposed 2 items and next pages 7 items):

`per_page = 7
    @comments = @content.comments.page(params[:page]).per(per_page).padding((per_page-2) * -1)`